# Is it possible to use mobile device as Cellular antenna to make the mobiel range be high?

Tags: android, mobile, cellular-network

In case i have Cellular antenna in some place , and there are 2 mobile devices ( lets call them a1, a2 ) that located in different places.

Device a1 is in the range of this Cellular antenna  - but device a2 are not in this  Cellular antenna range.

My question is:

Is it possible to use the a1 device to make the Cellular antenna range longer - and
in this way to make device a2 be in the range of this Cellular antenna ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you propose is a kind of mesh networking for Cellular wireless. However, cellular is a very centralized technology: you can not just mimic a cell controller ([BTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_transceiver_station)) on a cell phone, because it has completely different (and much more complex) functionality.

There are two possible alternatives, though:

- **[Wireless Mesh Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network)** which work hop-by-hop, often based on the Wireless LAN 802.11 standard - these do not allow to forward your mobile calls, but should work on WiFi equipped mobile phones.
- **[Picocells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picocell)** are offered by some DSL + Mobile providers to increase the Cellular coverage. They contain a low-power Cell which is connected to the provider's network via DSL.